# Javascript/Html removing disable attribute on Textboxes in a Listview

Tags: javascript, html, listview

I have a asp:listview of Types and Addresses for data in a Database. On button click I change the innerhtml of button to different text and I need to remove the disabled attribute on the corresponding input textbox for type and address. Whats happening is when I click on the button it removes the disabled attribute for the first row in the listview but not for the correponding one for the one I'm clicking. for example heres an example of the listview and what its doing

Type "/t/t/t/t/t/t/t"  Address

TxtBox      TxtBoxTxtBoxTxtBox  EditBtn DeleteBtn

TxtBox      TxtBoxTxtBoxTxtBox  EditBtn DeleteBtn  /**for example if i clicked this edit button it would remove the disable from the record above not this row

TxtBox      TxtBoxTxtBoxTxtBox  EditBtn DeleteBtn

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function changeText(button) { 
            button.innerHTML="Save";              
            document.getElementById('Type').removeAttribute('disabled');
            document.getElementById('Address').removeAttribute('disabled');    
</script>

<body>  
  <div>Addresses</div>
   <br />   
        <div>
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1" >
    <EmptyDataTemplate>No records found.</EmptyDataTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="sort" style="border:solid 1px black;width:40%;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <a href="#">Type</a>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <a href="#">Address</a>
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                   <input size="8" type="text" ID="Type" disabled="disabled" value="<%# Eval("Type")%>" />
                </td>
                <td>
                   <input size="9" type="text" ID="Address" disabled="disabled" value="<%# Eval("street")%> <%# Eval("City")%> <%# Eval("State")%>" />                     
                </td>
                <td>
                   <button id="editBtn" type="button" onclick="changeText(this)">Edit</button> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

get current tr, not document:

```
  function changeText(button) { 
        var row=button.parentNode.parentNode;
        button.innerHTML="Save";              
        row.querySelector('#Type').removeAttribute('disabled');
        row.querySelector('#Address').removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
```

Comment: Nah that didn't work, parentElement isn't an option for button

Comment: IE ? I changed to parentNode

Comment: I'm in FF. parentNode isn't an option either

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/JG4Vu/ this not works in FF ? If it works, show your result html, something wrong with it i bet.